# Code Tag Association to Syntax Highlighting Request

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, tags, syntax-highlighting

> Have looked at [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work) and in my opinion Classic ASP should fall into the `<!-- language: lang-vb -->` hint.

Being active in the [asp-classic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp-classic) tag questions I've noticed that a lot of them don't show the code syntax highlighting correctly.

What does Markdown currently do with Classic ASP code, the majority of which are usually [vbscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vbscript) but even that doesn't appear to highlight correctly.

I've found myself editing code blocks and adding

```
<!-- language: lang-vb -->
```

---

> **Update:**
>
> Not sure below is appropriate as [@ChrisF ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf) has confirmed the code hint
>
> ```
> <!-- language: lang-vb -->
> ```
>
> is already associated with [vbscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vbscript).

Is this something that could be associated to either [asp-classic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp-classic) or [vbscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vbscript) tags?
It might make more sense to associate it with [vbscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vbscript) because [asp-classic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp-classic) can use other scripting engines besides [vbscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vbscript).

If it was associated to [vbscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vbscript) it would save a lot of meaningless edits.

Comment: The problem is that you have two entirely separate types of code, the VBScript code, and the markup code.  Each requires different code highlighting logic.  This is the same problem that many web-based development tags have in which it has code blocks that can be HTML, CSS, Javascript, VBScript, etc. in different code blocks (possible multiple different ones within a single question).

Comment: Sorry @Servy I'm must be missing the point? Most [tag:asp-classic] code samples are straight [tag:vbscript] (with the exception `<%` and `%>` around them, which Markdown seems to handle ok anyway). If someone posted a large HTML page with ASP littered through it I wouldn't take a second glance, it can stay as is.

Comment: The tag [tag:vbscript] already has the `lang-vb` language associated with it.

Comment: @ChrisF Thanks for confirming, just notice when a question contains [tag:vbscript] and [tag:asp-classic] it doesn't always apply the `<!-- language: lang-vb -->` hint as I'd expect.

Comment: @Lankymart - That might be down to the other tags on the question.

Comment: @ChrisF: Can I ask how this association is established in the first place? I was going to create a question/feature-request on Meta about this but you might be able to resolve it without needing to go that far. Right now the GLSL tag should really be associated with C syntax highlighting, but no such association exists. I was hoping it might be something as simple as adding `<!-- language: lang-c -->` to the tag wiki, but that is not how it works in the `vbscript` tag. Is this something that is hidden from normal users and not editable otherwise?

Comment: @Andon it's a moderator only option. Raise a feature request question.

Comment: We need one for the python-fu tag too, its still a pretty fresh tag by the looks of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your edit points out, this is done for the [vbscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vbscript) tag already. All questions with this tag will automatically be highlighted using the VB language highlighter.

It wouldn't be appropriate to apply the same treatment to the [asp-classic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp-classic) tag, since, [looking at those questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp-classic+-vbscript), they tend to show code snippets from a variety of languages other than VB. If VB syntax highlighting is appropriate, the question should have *some* tag that suggests they're writing VB code.

As such, I'm declaring that this has been [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). As mentioned in the comments, if you see other tags that need to have their default syntax highlighting mode enabled or changed, please post a new feature request.