# How to add (or suggest) a tag language association for syntax highlighting?

Tags: support, tags, syntax-highlighting

I looked at the `xamarin` and `xamarin-forms` tag wikis, and there does not appear to be an association with a language for syntax highlighting for either of these. It does make sense, since many possibilities exist e.g. `lang-cs`, `lang-java`, `lang-c`, `lang-xml` depending on whether a code-snippet is C# or native to platform, or XAML markup. So I figure I should specify the syntax highlighting tag myself in my SO questions and answers.

But this got me thinking, if there was an obvious single language association that would help, how would I specify that in the tag's wiki, or request that it be specified?

I did try "improve tag wiki", and scrolled to bottom, but did not see where the language association on a tag that definitely has one (`java`) is specified.

Answer (score 5):

Originally posted [my question on meta.stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258817/how-to-add-or-suggest-a-tag-wiki-language-association-for-syntax-highlighting), these days the wrong place for this. Thanks to helpful comments there from @slugster, and a search on SO Meta, I came across [this question and answer that seemed to apply](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254084/code-tag-association-to-syntax-highlighting-request). Answer being in the comments, to [post as a feature-request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254084/code-tag-association-to-syntax-highlighting-request#comment41754_254084) for tag association with a language for syntax highlighting.

Comment: Correct. Moderators can change these for any tag at any time, just need to show support.