# Request to set GitHub Actions tag default syntax highlighting to YAML

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, syntax-highlighting

Please set the default language for [github-actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/github-actions) to `lang-yaml`.

The workflows and actions for GitHub Actions are described in YAML files (for reference: https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions).

Here are several recent examples where defaulting the language would be helpful:

- [Different gradle output in Github Actions VM and local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62049871/different-gradle-output-in-github-actions-vm-and-local)
- [What is "uses" directive in github actions used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62045478/what-is-uses-directive-in-github-actions-used-for)
- [Github Actions: missing telegram token or user list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61957795/github-actions-missing-telegram-token-or-user-list)

YAML syntax highlighting is available as per [YAML highlighting doesn't work on StackExchange sites but is supported by Google Prettify](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/255968/yaml-highlighting-doesnt-work-on-stackexchange-sites-but-is-supported-by-google/)

Syntax highlighting request as per [Changes to syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/72082/209031) and [How to add (or suggest) a tag language association for syntax highlighting?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297101/1366033).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does indeed make sense; I’ve set the default highlighter for the tag to `lang-yaml`.