# Request to set Azure Pipelines tag default syntax highlighting to YAML

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, syntax-highlighting

Please set the default language for [azure-pipelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-pipelines) to `lang-yaml`.

The new pipelines are described in YAML files, the old ones were only configurable via GUI ([reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/pipelines-get-started?view=azure-devops)).

Here are several recent examples where defaulting the language would be helpful:

- [Getting 'A task is missing. The pipeline references a task called 'Cache'.' error in Azure Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63705723/getting-a-task-is-missing-the-pipeline-references-a-task-called-cache-erro)
- [Why showing Unexpected value 'pool' error when put it into a template yaml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63712736/why-showing-unexpected-value-pool-error-when-put-it-into-a-template-yaml-file)
- [Is there a way to create an array in powershell and loop through it in Azure DevOps YAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63623006/is-there-a-way-to-create-an-array-in-powershell-and-loop-through-it-in-azure-dev)

Azure DevOps Pipelines are similar to GitHub Actions Workflows, for which a [similar default syntax highlighting request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397830/request-to-set-github-actions-tag-default-syntax-highlighting-to-yaml) was already completed.

YAML syntax highlighting is available as per [YAML highlighting doesn't work on StackExchange sites but is supported by Google Prettify](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/255968/yaml-highlighting-doesnt-work-on-stackexchange-sites-but-is-supported-by-google/)

Syntax highlighting request as per [Changes to syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/72082/209031) and [How to add (or suggest) a tag language association for syntax highlighting?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297101/1366033).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agreed, that makes perfect sense. Done!