# Set the default syntax highlighting of the GitLab-CI tag to YAML

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, syntax-highlighting

Please set the default language for [gitlab-ci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gitlab-ci) to `lang-yaml`.

The GitLab CI/CD pipeline configuration is described in a YAML file (for reference: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/).

Here are several recent examples where defaulting the language would be helpful:

- [What does `only: -master` in gitlab-ci.yml match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65578767/what-does-only-master-in-gitlab-ci-yml-match)
- [Files removed during pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65576586/files-removed-during-pipeline)
- [How to configure gitlab-ce domain url on docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65538036/how-to-configure-gitlab-ce-domain-url-on-docker)

This is very similar to the [syntax highlighting request for GitHub Actions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397830/request-to-set-github-actions-tag-default-syntax-highlighting-to-yaml) (GitHub's CI / CD).

---

YAML syntax highlighting is available as per [YAML highlighting doesn't work on StackExchange sites but is supported by Google Prettify](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/255968/yaml-highlighting-doesnt-work-on-stackexchange-sites-but-is-supported-by-google/)

Syntax highlighting request as per [Changes to syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/72082/209031) and [How to add (or suggest) a tag language association for syntax highlighting?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297101/1366033).