# Request to set YAML tag default syntax highlighting to lang-yaml

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, syntax-highlighting

Please set the default language for [yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yaml) to `lang-yaml`.

Here are several examples where defaulting the language would be helpful:

- [How do I break a string over multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790454/how-do-i-break-a-string-over-multiple-lines)
- [YAML Multi-Line Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23657086/yaml-multi-line-arrays)
- [What is the use of the pipe symbol in YAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15540635/what-is-the-use-of-the-pipe-symbol-in-yaml)

YAML syntax highlighting is available as per [YAML highlighting doesn't work on StackExchange sites but is supported by Google Prettify](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/255968/yaml-highlighting-doesnt-work-on-stackexchange-sites-but-is-supported-by-google/)

Syntax highlighting request as per [Changes to syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/72082/209031) and [How to add (or suggest) a tag language association for syntax highlighting?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297101/1366033).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was implemented by [Bhargav Rao](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4099593/bhargav-rao).