# Add syntax highlighting language 'default' for tags [swift2.2] and [swift3] (currently none)

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, syntax-highlighting

*Based on [this Q&A regarding tag language association](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297101/how-to-add-or-suggest-a-tag-language-association-for-syntax-highlighting), specifically [this related comment by moderator ChrisF](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254084/code-tag-association-to-syntax-highlighting-request#comment41754_254084) (to [this related thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254084/code-tag-association-to-syntax-highlighting-request)), I post this minor tag modification request as a feature request here on the meta.*

---

### Feature request: add *Code Language (used for syntax highlighting): 'default'* to [swift2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift2.2) and [swift3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift3) tags (currently 'none')

The tags [swift2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift2.2) and [swift3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift3) have no associated *Code Language (used for syntax highlighting)*, which means that [these tags will be associated with *'none'* as their language code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work). Consequently, questions tagged with only these tags (or, with these and other *'none'* language code tags) will not be syntax highlighted.

Generally OP:s tend to tag questions with more than a single tag, in so most likely including an additional tag that contains *'default'*<sup>*†*</sup> as associated *Code Language*, so for most [swift2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift2.2) and [swift3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift3) Q&A:s this is not an issue. In cases where these are single tags, however, code included in questions/answers end up without syntax highlighting. E.g., to pick a few

- [How to use #selector(myMethodName) in a protocol extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36174831/how-to-use-selectormymethodname-in-a-protocol-extension)
- [Algorithm: check for duplication in Swift array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36777640/algorithm-check-for-duplication-in-swift-array)
- [No access to my variable outside do-catch block in Swift 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36760185/no-access-to-my-variable-outside-do-catch-block-in-swift-2-2)
- [swift 3: How to extend [UInt8] to add getUInt32BE function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36858921/swift-3-how-to-extend-uint8-to-add-getuint32be-function) (manually set the language association manually in the Q&A code blocks)

**Feature pros**

Adding an associated code language (default) for these tags will allow syntax highlighting for questions single-tagged by these (as compared to no syntax highlighting at all).

**Feature cons**

As the alternative is no syntax highlighting, I see no cons in this request, other than the work needed by the administration to include this addition to these tags. I might add that the [swift2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift2.2) tag is possibly a somewhat temporary tag, whereas we can expect [swift3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift3) to persist and be active just as the [swift2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift2) tag is/has been.

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>It seems as if setting *default* code language association is sufficient to produce satisfying syntax highlighting for Swift, see e.g. [this single-tagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36876100/reference-self-in-swift-instance-member-declaration) [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) thread</sub>.

Comment: It's not a massive deal to change the default language for a tag - but the general approach is that the community tags with a main language (eg: swift) then uses a version specific tag if required (eg: swift2.2) - which not only exposes the question to more people able to answer it and hopefully makes it obvious a version specific response is required but also sorts out the highlighting anyway...

Comment: @JonClements I see, thanks. For Swift tags specifically, e.g. the [tag:swift2] tag info page, I've (prior to your comment) interpreted the intent as wanting to avoid dual tagging; either using e.g. [tag:swift] or [tag:swift2], but avoiding both. If this is not the case, however, as you say adding the [tag:swift] to Q&A:s (whenever I stumble over these) with only sub-ver. tags will fix the highlighting issue described here. I'm uncertain if this is a common approach for high-rep Swift users however, if my mind serves me right I've seen rollbacks for adding [tag:swift] tag for sub-version Q:s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I saw no harm in it, so I set the syntax highlighting for these to "default". Didn't even know moderators could do that, before reading this question. You learn something new every day.

I really don't like seeing questions tagged with only [swift2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift2), [swift2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift2.2), and [swift3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift3), though, as many regulars only watch [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift). I'd recommend adding a main Swift tag to each of these if you see a question missing it.

Comment: Thanks. Starting from now, I'll add the [tag:swift] tag whenever I stumble over swift_version/subversion tagged questions missing it; referring to this meta post in case such tag edits were to be criticized.

Comment: I believe that if you haven't done this, the community would have more motivation of using tags right, instead of workaround the system.