# lang-swift syntax highlighting for [swiftui] and [swift5] tags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, syntax-highlighting

Certain tags, like [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) and [swift4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift4), will automatically apply a “code language” (used for syntax highlighting) of `lang-swift`. But newer Swift tags, like [swift4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift4.1), [swift4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift4.2), [swift5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift5), [swift5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift5.1), or [swiftui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swiftui) do not. There was a feature request ([Add syntax highlighting language 'default' for tags [swift2.2] and [swift3] (currently none)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321824/1271826)) a while ago for earlier Swift tags, but these newer tags don’t bear this designation.

Can we add the automatic `lang-swift` formatting to these newer Swift tags?

I’d especially like to see it for [swiftui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swiftui) because whereas [swift5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift5) questions, for example, will often also bear the [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) tag, too, [swiftui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swiftui) questions frequently don’t (probably because authors are often specifically looking for answers specific to the declarative nature of SwiftUI, and not soliciting general Swift imperative programming solutions, even though it technically is Swift 5.1).