# Make `angular2` and `angular` (not `angularjs`) tags bind to JavaScript / ES2015 syntax highlighter

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

Based on [Code Tag Association to Syntax Highlighting Request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254084/code-tag-association-to-syntax-highlighting-request#comment41754_254084),

could someone please make `angular2` and `angular` (not `angularjs`) tags bind to the JavaScript/ES2015 and HTML syntax highlighting?

I.e. when I use `angular2` tag, it would find the TS code snippets and highlight them.

TS2 is the language in which Angular2 apps are typically written. ES2015 is TS2 minus types. Templates are kind of HTML.

Comment: There's no syntax highlighter that's specific to TypeScript. The TypeScript tag is using `lang-js` for its highlighting (http://stackoverflow.com/tags/typescript/info). Also, note that Angular2 apps can also be written in ES2015.

Comment: Ok, changed to JS